# Is there any difference between remembers everything and never forgets?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

If we have the two sentences:

> John remembers everything.

and

> John never forgets.

Are there any nuances or tones that give different meaning to the two phrases.

Comment: I'd be more likely to say, "John never forgets" when I mean John holds a grudge.

Comment: Also the first sounds like you are impressed with the ability of remembering, whereas the second sounds more like he will remember specific things forever, grudges but also favours.

Comment: I'm not sure which phrase is more disturbing: "an elephant that never forgets" or "an elephant that remembers everything."

Answer (score 1):

Both are syntactically equivalent, however, the difference will be largely dependent on the context AND the way you delivered those sentences.